# Transition from Azure AD v1 authentication to Azure AD v2 authentication

Tags: outlook-restapi

I want to migrate an application from **Azure AD v1 authentication** to **Azure AD v2**. Does that mean that the existing tokens that I have stored won't work after I switch to AD v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the refresh tokens? No, v1 refresh tokens will not work if sent to the v2 endpoints.

Comment: Jason, Thank you. I would be grateful if you pointed me to an article or documentation that would help me make migration from v1 to v2.

Comment: I don't know of a specific migration doc, but there's https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/ which might be helpful.